# Oracle SQL Query -> Count 2 columns under 2 different conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have a table that looks like this:

> ```
> YEAR        RESOLUTION_DATE      CREATION_DATE  
>
> 2013                             2013/02/18
> 2012                             2012/05/26
> 2009                             2009/11/11
> 2013          2013/12/08         2013/12/01
> 2000                             2000/17/31
> 2007                             2007/12/08
> 2012                             2012/12/08
> 2012          2012/03/23         2012/03/10 
> 2012                             2012/12/08
> 2007                             2007/01/17
> 2012          2012/01/17         2012/01/10
> 2009                             2009/02/14
> ```

I am trying to make a query that will output the following:

> ```
> YEAR      COUNT_RESOLUTION_DATE      COUNT_CREATION_DATE  
> 2000               0                          1
> 2007               0                          2
> 2009               0                          2
> 2011               0                          0
> 2012               2                          5
> 2013               1                          2
> ```

The caveat is that I would like the query to count the number of RESOLUTION_DATE by YEAR, where the RESOLUTION_DATE IS NOT NULL and i want to count ALL CREATION_DATE's. The SQL is needed for an oracle database.

Comment: Why is `count_creation_date` 0 for the year 2000?  Shouldn't it be 1 since there is a row with a `year` of 2000 (and a `creation_date` of 2008-- that seems odd but I don't see why you wouldn't count it)?  Why is the `count_creation_date` for 2011 23?  I only see 1 row with a `year` of 2011 (and that somehow has a `creation_date` of 2007).

Comment: You've an invalid month for the year 2000

Comment: I created dummy numbers initally. I have now updated them...they should make sense now. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the non-NULL resolution dates counted, this should work:

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN RESOLUTION_DATE IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS COUNT_RESOLUTION_DATE, 
COUNT(CREATION_DATE) AS COUNT_CREATION_DATE
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY YEAR
ORDER BY YEAR;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I realized that COUNT will always skip null values...awesome Ken!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(RESOLUTION_DATE) AS COUNT_RESOLUTION_DATE, 
COUNT(CREATION_DATE) AS COUNT_CREATION_DATE
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY YEAR
ORDER BY YEAR
```

Comment: Hi, but i only want to count the resolution_date where is it not null. and i want to count ALL creation_date's.

Comment: `count` skips null values.